# AppFabric support for Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, appfabric

I am currently working on a project that is using AppFabric libraries. These are the libraries:
[image]

I have tried to donwload AppFabric from this link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15848#Instructions), but i get an error stating that my verison of windows is not supported. (currently using Windows 10)

error message:

[image]

Is there any support for AppFabric on Windows 10? and if there isn't how am i supposed to work around this issue?

hope you guys can help. Thanks

Comment: AppFabric caching has [been retired](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#which-azure-cache-offering-is-right-for-me). Microsoft has been warning of this for almost 2 years now, offering Redis as an alternative. I don't think you want to get stuck using an already retired technology

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft has planned to stop support at 4/2/2016 but has decided to extend support until next year](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabric/2015/04/02/microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-ends-support-422016/).

It might be a big challenge to get it running with Windows 10. Did you try to install the latest cumulative update, which is as far as I know [CU7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3092423)? Maybe that helps.

If possible I would recommend to find an alternative.

Comment: AppFabric Caching on Azure has already [been retired](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#which-azure-cache-offering-is-right-for-me). All relevant pages have been warning of this for around 2 years, recommending Redis instead